# Getting "self._form.on is not a function" when using node-requests in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, electron

I'm building an Electron application with Vue.js as the client side framework. When  I try to run a node script I get **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: self._form.on is not a function**

I'm not sure if this is due to it being run on the browser via electron but it is working fine when I run the script via Node in the console. Is it even possible to run this node script client side? I'm running the node file via one of the frontend vue.js components by requiring the file. **let raffleScript = require('../raffles/index.js');**

**Node script:**

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

var retryDelay = 300; 
var tasks = 200; 


var userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36';
var tasksComplete = 0;
var exportedCount = 0;
// Export the values
//setInterval(countUpdate, 4000);

initProxies();

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

async function initProxies() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
        submitRaffle(i);
        await sleep(retryDelay);
        // setTimeout(function () {
        //  submitRaffle(i);
        // }, retryDelay)
    }
}

function submitRaffle(taskNum) {
    var jar = require('request').jar()
    var request = require('request').defaults({
        jar: jar
    });


    console.log('Making request.............................');
    request({
        url: 'bungeedesign.com/dev',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        formData: 
        { firstname: 'James',
          name: '',
          lastname: 'Rogers',
          mobileNumber: '00000000',
          email: 'email@email.com',
          raffle_type: 'Development',
          checkbox_0: 'Backend',
          personal_or_business: 'Personal',
          model: 'Register Of Interests',
          'submit-0': 'Keep me posted' },
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        // console.log('REQ RES --------->>>> ', response);
        //console.log('Req Completed', response);
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error.............................');
            setTimeout(function () {
                submitRaffle(taskNum)
            }, retryDelay)
            return;
        }
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        if (response.statusCode == 302) {
            //if (JSON.parse(body).message == "successfully") {
                console.log('\x1b[1;32m', "[" + taskNum + "] - Raffle entry submitted");
                tasksComplete++;
                //module.exports.exportedCount = tasksComplete;
                console.log('\x1b[1;32m', "[" + taskNum + "] - " + tasksComplete + " Entries submitted.")
            //}
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                submitRaffle(taskNum)
            }, retryDelay)
            return;
        }
    });
}


// Increment Exports

// function countUpdate() {
//  module.exports.exportedCount = exportedCount++;
// }
```

**Main.vue Component (script)**

```
let raffleScript = require('../raffles/index.js');
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                amount: '0'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async register() {
                try {
                    await AuthenticationService.register({
                        key: this.key
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    this.error = error.response.data.error
                }
            },

            async entryAmountChange() {
                let entryAmount = document.querySelector('.tsEntryAmount').value;
                let replaced = entryAmount.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                document.querySelector('.tsEntryAmount').value = replaced;               
            },
            async runRaffle() {
                console.log("Log: ", raffleScript.exportedCount);
                this.entryAmount = raffleScript.exportedCount;
            },
            runTime: function() {
                function checkTime(i) {
                    return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
                }

                function startTime() {
                    let today = new Date(),
                        h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
                        m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
                        s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
                    let timeElement = document.querySelector('#time');
                    let time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                    // this.time = "dsdsd";
                    document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML = time;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        startTime()
                    }, 500);
                }
                startTime();
            },
            async getValues() {
                console.log("Log: ", raffleScript.tasksComplete);
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.runTime();
            this.getValues();
            this.runRaffle();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get it to work with the Node Requests module. I tried Axios and that worked although I had some issues with CORS. I then came across Needle https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle which worked perfectly!

Not sure why Node Requests is not working when using formData.